# Why Robert pointing his lasers to the room's laser?

Tags: plot-explanation, entrapment

In *Entrapment (1999)*, Robert & Virginia are going to steal China Mask.
They entered into destination from underground, & Robert bought some lasers.
[image]

Projecting them to lasers which are already attached in the room.

[image]

Comment: @Napolean Wilson, I am asking why he is poiting the lasers to room lasers.

Comment: @Napolean Wilson, Movie lacks detailed IMDB synopsis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not clearly stated** but it seems likely that the intention is to disable the lazers that are not horizontal.

By doing so it reduces the 3d-grid/matrix created by the lazers at the ceiling pointing down leaving only the **horizontally pointing** lazers which Viginia can avoid with her gymnastics.

[image]

Comment: Plus, it's a really good excuse to do some sultry gymnastics.

Answer (score 2):

My (non-technical) understanding of this sort of laser security system is that it functions by detecting when a beam is interrupted and tripping an alarm.

On one end of the room is a laser projector, directly across from that is a sensor.  If the sensor ever *fails* to detect the beam that *should be* pointed at it, the alarm is sounded.

Robert sets up his own laser beam projectors and points them at the receiving sensors, so that even if the *real beam* gets interrupted, the sensor won't realize it (because it's still sensing light from the "fake beam.")

Comment: I don't disagree but the beams being disabled would be **pointing down from the ceiling**...and we don't see any of those at all so my assumption is that there were *vertical/angled* beams creating a 3d matrix but they only need to disable the vertical ones

Comment: If the sensors are on the ceiling (as they appear to be in the screenshots provided) then the beams would be pointing *up* from somewhere on the floor.  I agree with you that only vertical/angled beams appear to have been thus disabled.  It's easy enough to get the necessary angles to disable the verticals, but getting the angles to disable the horizontals would be harder since he couldn't do it from inside the hole he's hiding in.  So, they left those alone and Virginia just avoided them.  Both of our answers are correct, addressing different aspects of the scene in question.